# cell2mat produces wrong output size

Tags: octave, cell-array

I have a cell matrix with size **32x32** where each cell is an **8x8** matrix and all values are floats. I use DCT to each **8x8** cell and after that I assign each matrix to another empty cell matrix. So, the new cell matrix is **32x32** as expected and when I use `cell2mat` with said matrix, I get size **556x556** instead of **256x256**.

```
first_arr=mat2cell(inputArr,8*ones(1,size(img,1)/8),8*ones(1,size(img,2)/8),1);
c=cell(32);
for i=1:32
 for j=1:32
  temp=cell2mat(first_arr(i,j));
  temp1=dct(temp);
  for k=1:8
   for l=1:8
    if(some_condition)
     temp1(k,l)=0;
    endif
   endfor
  endfor
 inverted=idct(temp1);##inverted dct
 c(i,j)=inverted; 
 endfor
endfor
temp2=cell2mat(c);
```

After the execution I have the following results:

> **size(c)=32x32**
> **size(temp2)=556x556**

If I use `cell2mat` with `first_arr` the resulted size is `256x256`.

Can somebody explain why that is happening?

I tried everything and I can't seem to find a solution to that. I checked the sizes of each matrix on every step and everything is `8x8` as expected

Comment: I removed the MATLAB tag because this is not valid MATLAB code. `temp=cell2mat(first_arr(i,j))` would be better written as `temp=first_array{i,j}`. Likewise, it should be `c{i,j}=inverted`. (Is it an Octave extension that it works with round brackets?)

Comment: Thank you @CrisLuengo for your edit and for your reply. I can not find any explanation for this issue. I tried your recommendation but it doesn't work. Nothing changed in the result. As for the round brackets I don't know, but it seems to work. Finally, I used ```blockproc``` as recommend by a friend of mine and the issue now is solved

Comment: Yup, it's an Octave extension: if you assign to elements of a cell using round brackets like `c(whatever) = blah` and the RHS "blah" is not already a cell array, then entirety of the RHS is implicitly wrapped in a scalar cell. Documented at https://octave.org/doc/v6.4.0/Indexing-Cell-Arrays.html#Indexing-Cell-Arrays near the text "Note, that the above can also...".